# Iniciar sesión en Página web con Python y Selenium

Tags: python, web, selenium

Estoy intentando iniciar sesión en una página web con Python (versión 3.9.13) y Selenium, al principio he estado probando a que me iniciara sesión en mi cuenta de correo ya que habían más tutoriales. Pero no he podido hacerlo debido a que Google ya no permite hacer uso de programas de terceros, pero al menos el código me escribía automaticamente mi cuenta de correo y le daba a "Siguiente" y hasta ahí llegaba.
Volviendo a mi principal problema, he aprovechado el mismo código para entrar en la página de Fusión Solar, pero ahora el código no me escribe mi cuenta de correo ni la contraseña y tampoco hace click en el "login".
Y no sé si es un tema de seguridad de la propia página o por el código.

Este  es el código.

```
from selenium import webdriver  
import time  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
print("test case started")  
#open Google Chrome browser  
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  
#maximize the window size  
driver.maximize_window()  
#delete the cookies  
driver.delete_all_cookies()  
#navigate to the url  
driver.get("https://eu5.fusionsolar.huawei.com/unisso/login.action?decision=1&service=https%3A%2F%2Fregion01eu5.fusionsolar.huawei.com%2Funisess%2Fv1%2Fauth%3Fservice%3D%252Fnetecowebext%252Fhome%252Findex.html%2523%252FLOGIN")  
#identify the user name text box and enter the value  
driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("Correo")  
time.sleep(2)  
#identify the password text box and enter the value   
driver.find_element_by_id("value").send_keys("Contraseña")  
time.sleep(3)  
#click on the next button  
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='submitDataverify']").click()  
time.sleep(3)
```

Gracias por la ayuda.

Hola tenía un fallo a la hora de hacer el login, pero ahora funciona bien, el error del login estaba en la URL pero ya está solucionado.
Muchas gracias.
Aquí os dejo el código final.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time

service = ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

print("Test case started")  
# Maximize window
driver.maximize_window()

# Delete the cookies  
driver.delete_all_cookies()

# Navigate to the url  
driver.get("https://eu5.fusionsolar.huawei.com/unisso/login.action?service=%2Funisess%2Fv1%2Fauth%3Fservice%3D%252Fnetecowebext%252Fhome%252Findex.html")

# Get element
username = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'username')

# Wait
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# Type email
username.send_keys('Correo')

#Get element password
password = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'value')

# Wait
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# Type password
password.send_keys('Contraseña')

# Wait
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

time.sleep(5)

# Click on login
Buton = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'btn_outerverify')

# Wait
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

Buton.click()

time.sleep(5)

driver.get("https://region01eu5.fusionsolar.huawei.com/pvmswebsite/assets/build/index.html#/home/kpi")

print('Test case completed')
```

Comment: Estoy intentando conectarme con la nube de huawei para optener los datos de mi instalacion solar a través de su openAPI. Es facil y funciona muy bien. Lo he probado con la cuenta de un amigo. A mi me esta costando mucho que me activen la cuenta porque necesitan la autorizacion del instalador. Supongo que el intentar logarse con selenium es para poder acceder a los datos y automatizar los excedentes. Has podido acceder bien a la web y recuperar los datos?. No conozco mucho selenium y es por dedicarle mas o menos tiempo a aprender. Si quieres informacion sobre openAPI, dímelo.

Comment: Hola @FernandoH. Si, he podido acceder a la web y he podido ver todos los datos con Selenium y lo tengo funcionando todos los días y no me ha fallado. Tienes el código completo arriba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

En algunas páginas, para evitar mal uso por automatización, ponen algún elemento para "bloquear" botones o campos de entrada y en otras ocasiones los esconden con alguna clase.

En esos casos puedes utilizar:

```
driver.implicitly_wait()
```

En este caso puedes ver que el `input` está dentro de `div` anidados si abres el inspector de tu navegador.

[image: Inspector]

Cuando intentas obtener el componente por su "id" y enviar el comando en la misma línea, no das tiempo a que el elemento en realidad sea "obtenido".

Si separas el comando en dos líneas funcionará correctamente:

```
# Get element
username = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'username')

# Type email
username.send_keys('Correo')
```

**Nota:** el método `find_element_by_id` va a ser eliminado, la documentación menciona que se debe reemplazar por `find_element`.

[image: Se escribió "Correo" en el campo "username"]

De igual forma creo que sería conveniente que le dieras siempre un tiempo de espera entre comandos (Tal como lo pongo en el ejemplo).

**Nota:** Cuando incluyas código en tus preguntas, procura que sean ejemplos completos para que puedan ser utilizados al copiar y pegar. Modifiqué las librerías que importas y el código para obtener el servicio y el driver para que sea funcional para cualquier persona que lo desee copiar.

Ejemplo completo:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

service = ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

print("Test case started")  
# Maximize window
driver.maximize_window()

# Delete the cookies  
driver.delete_all_cookies()

# Navigate to the url  
driver.get("https://eu5.fusionsolar.huawei.com/unisso/login")

# Get element
username = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'username')

# Wait
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# Type email
username.send_keys('Correo')

print('Test case completed')
```

Comment: Nota aparte, la URL que utilizas tiene argumentos que no son necesarios, por eso la modifiqué en la respuesta

Comment: Gracias HeytalePazguato, me has ayudado a avanzar, pero ahora tengo el siguiente problema. Cuando el programa me hace el "login", no ocurre nada.

Comment: Buen día, por favor crea una nueva pregunta e incluye el código que tienes ahora y el/los errores que aparecen

Comment: Es importante mantener una sola pregunta por publicación, de esa forma cuando otros usuarios tienen problemas similares pueden encontrar las respuestas de forma organizada. Si anidamos varias preguntas en una misma publicación entonces es imposible encontrar respuestas en las publicaciones de los demás. Saludos! (Si quieres pon el link de tu nueva pregunta en un comentario y lo reviso)

Comment: Hola HeytalePazguato, ya está solucionado, el problema era la URL que estaba en tú código. Pero ahora va bien. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: No hay de que, saludos!